# query in mysql database to parse specific word and display 2 words before and after to it

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I need help in building a query which would search a word in a sentence, once found it should show 2 words before and after to the searched word.

**Example 1 :-**

```
Input Sentence :- "Hi my computer is down at 10 am due to power issue"
search keyword ( which is pre-defined ) :- down
expected output :- "computer is down at 10" ( 2 words before and after of the searched keyword )
```

**Example 2 :-**

```
Input Sentence :- "Hi my database is down at morning 8am due to memory"
search keyword ( which is pre-defined ) :- down
expected output :- "database is down at morning" ( 2 words before and after of the searched keyword )
```

For Query building, kindly consider table name as "input" and column which holds the sentence as "description"

Thanks for your help!!

Punit

Comment: MySQL regex are for validation only, not for extracting text. Do it in your code

Comment: Smells like homework. Check the LOCATE function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate to get index of the search word and index of spaces before and after found word start index. Then just combine results

Comment: Using `LOCATE` on this task is masochistic.